# Java Scanner, No such element exception while reading mulitple lines

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read multiple line from a file using java scanner. Each line has strings separated using comma, but there is no comma at the end of line. My text file contains value like below

98792203000000005091,89065012012341234100000000000167,084952103900000015
98792203000000005091,89065012012341234100000000000167,084952103900000015

The scanner is throwing a no element exception, it works fine if I add a comma t the end of line, but the original file will not have a comma. How do I make work

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(outPutFile);
        int outputDataStart = Integer.parseInt(outputDataStartLine);
        skipLines(sc, outputDataStart);
        sc.useDelimiter(",");
        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            OutputVariables outputVariables = new OutputVariables();
            outputVariables.setIccid(sc.next());
            outputVariables.setImsi(sc.next());
            outputVariables.setKey(sc.next());
            outputVariables.setPIN1(sc.next());
            outputVariables.setPUK1(sc.next());

            outputVariables.setPIN2(sc.next());
            outputVariables.setPUK2(sc.next());
            outputVariables.setPINAdm(sc.next());
            outputVariables.setAccount(sc.next());
            outputVariables.setKIC(sc.next());
            outputVariables.setKID(sc.next());
            outputVariables.setKIK(sc.next());
            outputVariables.setOPCKey(sc.next());
            OutputVariableList.add(outputVariables);
        }
```

Comment: Edited to add code

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the scanner to parse more values from a line of text than there are values. This is happening because you're calling `next()` without first checking `hasNext()`. Since you've told it to use the comma as the delimeter, it's hitting the end of the line continuing on to the next line until it finds the next comma.

Consider this CSV:

```
A,B,C,D
```

If you call `next()` after you parse the "D", the scanner will throw a NoSuchElementException.

It is not clear what you're attempting to do. If you're attempting to convert what is effectively a CSV into an object, then your best bet would be to use the Scanner to read each line, and then a `String.split()` call to split that line into parts.

If you're trying to parse *multiple* lines into an object, you'll of course need to figure out where your boundary is -- every fifteen comma separated values? every three lines? -- and apply that logic while collecting your segments.

As a simplified example, consider this collection of lines:

```
A,B,C,D
E,F,G,H
I,J,K
```

You would first use the Scanner to read line-by-line, and then use split each line apart and create the individual objects. Notice the last line is malformed -- you'll need to trap for that and catch it to avoid the NoSuchElementException.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
while(sc.hasNext()) {
  String line = sc.next();
  String[] parts = line.split(",");

  if(parts.length != 4) {
    System.err.println("Invalid line: " + line);
    continue; // skip this record, it is bad
  }

  // create your object here from parts
  Pojo example = new Pojo(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3]);
  // etc
}
```

Alternatively if you're just trying to create a single massive object -- eg *all* lines belong to the same record -- you could tell it to consider a newline as a delimeter in addition to a comma. That way, after you hit the last comma in the first line, you would call `next()` and it would parse until the end of the line; and then when you called `next()` again, it would parse starting on the *next* line until it reached a comma or the end of the line, whichever came first.

Answer (score 0):

Insteard of using `sc.useDelimiter(",")` use `sc.useDelimiter(",|\\n")` it would break by both `,` and `new line`

Answer (score -2):

I suggest you to use `BufferedReader` 
it has a method named `readLine()` 
first read a String then through the `string.split(",")` you can get the array of String

Comment: Thanks I used Buffered Reader, but instead of split I used String tokenizer, it worked